# animate: zoom background in CSS

Tags: css

I want to animate the background image (zoom from 100% to 120%)
The zoom from 100 to 120 works fine. After it zooms to 120, the image is set automatically to 100 and the same procedure starts again. 
I want to zoom it back. 
Like this: from 100 to 120 and than from 120 to 100. How is this possible?

```
.imageBlub{
    background: url('../Images/blub.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
    animation: animatedBackground 6s linear infinite;

}

@keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-size: 100% auto; }
    to {  background-size: 120% auto;}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest using `animation-direction: alternate;` giving:

```
animation: animatedBackground 6s linear alternate infinite;
```

This property value, as the name suggests, alternates the animation direction; first going 'forwards' (0 to 100%) and then going 'backwards (100% to 0).

References:

- [`animation-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction).

Comment: That's a brilliant one and is more simpler for this case than altering keyframes to produce the reverse effect.

Comment: Thank you both; and, Minas, I'm happy to have helped!